# PRoot: libudev: udev_monitor_new_from_netlink_fd: error getting socket: Permission denied

Tags: termux

I'm trying to get Steam running with Box64 on Ubuntu in PRoot. But I get errors.

Ptitseb, the developer of Box64 says it's probably because of
`libudev: udev_monitor_new_from_netlink_fd: error getting socket: Permission denied.` https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86/issues/699#issuecomment-1492968015
Is there a workaround?